# Confusion regarding jdk.tools in Eclipse/Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project that at one point had these lines about `jdk.tools`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

On my `Eclipse`, removing these lines would gave me an error of 
"Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8".

But my colleague used the same pom.xml (without those lines) and she did not see
the error.

Also, on a UNIX machine I could maven build without needing
those lines (this is expected, because the scope has been `system`).

The dependency tree related to this artifact is this:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
```

Comment: What lines did you remove? The whole `<dependency/>` section for `jdk.tools`? And your colleague had exactly the same project structure like no other poms with dependency management or so?

Comment: I removed the whole `<dependency/>` section for jdk.tools.  I am asking my colleagues to send me her `pom.xml` to run a `diff` against my copy.  Thanks!